What is this window latch called? (Part of octagonal window)
I have an octagonal window and this little part that holds the latch in broke off. Hoping to find the name of the replacement part if anyone knows what the latch is called. Thank you!



Is this a picture of what it looked like before, what broke off, or what's left?

@gnicko apologies, the part on the right had a vertical piece that held the horizontal piece in. That broke off and now. It's just the flat bottom piece. Trying to upload another pic

Try SWISCO.  They offer a wide variety of window and door replacement hardware.

Swisco found a close part for me and it worked thank you!
https://www.swisco.com/Telescoping-Push-Bar/pd/Awning-Window-Replacement-Operators/39-040
